# How to splice an array to insert array at specific position?

Tags: php, array-splice

```
$custom = Array(
            Array(
                'name'  =>  $name1,
                'url'   =>  $url1
            ),
            Array(
                'name'  =>  $name_a,
                'url'   =>  $url_a
            )
        );
```

I am attempting to splice the array with the following:

```
$bread_elem = array('name' => 'Golf', 'url' => $slug . $parent_slug);
array_splice($custom, 1, 0, $bread_elem);
```

I want my array to become the following, with the value of `$sale_bread_elem` inserted into position one within the array. I can't see what I am doing wrong.

```
$custom = Array(
            Array(
                'name'  =>  $name1,
                'url'   =>  $url1
            ),
            Array(
                'name'  =>  'Golf',
                'url'   =>  $slug . $parent_slug
            ),
            Array(
                'name'  =>  $name_a,
                'url'   =>  $url_a
            )
        );
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`array_splice`<sup>­*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_splice) takes an *array* of elements to insert. So the call should actually be

```
array_splice($custom, 1, 0, array($bread_elem));
```

Comment: **Note:** Does not preserve keys.