# Add element on specific position and move existing one

Tags: php, arrays

Hi there I have an key => value array. Key is numeric index and value is associative array. I want to add new element at a particular position and wants to move the existing one ahead. My array looks like

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
        [States ] => States
        [Call Count] => Call Count
        [Leads] => Leads
    )

 [1] => Array
    (
        [States] => AK
        [Call Count] => 0
        [Leads] => 
    )

 [2] => Array
    (
        [States] => AL
        [Call Count] => 0
        [Leads] => 
    )

 [3] => Array
    (
        [States] => AR
        [Call Count] => 0
        [Leads] => 
    )
)
```

Now I want to insert one index like `2=>array('States'=>'ABC','Call Count' =>5, 'Leads'=>2)` and wants index 2 to become 3 and 3 to become 4..... When I use

```
 array_slice($outboundSummaryData, 0, 2, true) +
            array('States ' => 'States', 'Call Count' => 'Call Count', 'Leads' => 'Leads') +
            array_slice($outboundSummaryData, 2, count($outboundSummaryData) - 2, true);
```

It overrides my 2 index.

When I use

```
array_splice($outboundSummaryData, 2, 0, array('States ' => 'States', 'Call Count' => 'Call Count', 'Leads' => 'Leads'));
```

It insert my new array elements as main indexes of the array.

Any Help?

Comment: why are you using associative array in the first place? having this as a normal array will make array_splice do what you want

Comment: You'd better use another data structure: list is what you need, not array.

Comment: It sounds like you want a sorted array. What are the criteria?

Comment: @FikriMarhan  Its a db result so I have to do with it :-(

Comment: @Gordon Simply wants to add new elements in array as sub array and move existing one ahead

Comment: @AwaisQarni if there is no sort order, the order is arbitrary, then you can simply append to the end. but apparently it's important for you to insert at offset 2, so how do you know that the array should be at offset 2?

Comment: @Gordon I need it at specific location. You can say its hardcoded

Comment: @hakre Thank you for the downvote. I have already searched but my creteria is different.

Comment: @hakre Please read question content before showing your expertise for downvoting

Comment: @AwaisQarni: Your criteria *might* be different (depends a bit where you want to split hair here) however different criteria do not needlessly qualify for a different question.

Comment: Also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977812/how-to-splice-an-array-to-insert-array-at-specific-position

Comment: Also after re-reading your question it's obvious you made a little mistake not understanding how inserting an array inside another array of array works. You just made a little mistake, the method work as announced. @Hendriq already wrote that to you about 15 minutes ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made it work with [`array_splice`](http://php.net/array_splice). And your datastructure can stay the same

```
$test = array(
    array('apple', 'juice'),
    array('ice', 'cream'),
    array('tea', 'pot'),
);

var_dump($test);

array_splice($test, 2, 0, array(2 => array('coffee', 'milk')));

var_dump($test);
```

Prety straightforward. The array that is added also needs the new index

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_array = array_merge( 
   array_slice($outboundSummaryData, 0, 2, true),
   array( 
          array(
                'States' => 'States',
                'Call Count' => 'Call Count', 
                'Leads' => 'Leads'
               ) 
        ),
   array_slice($outboundSummaryData, 2, count($outboundSummaryData) - 2, true)
);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => Array
        (
            [States] => States
            [Call Count] => Call Count
            [Leads] => Leads
        )

    [3] => 2
    [4] => 3
)
```

Answer (score 0):

well.. you could always use splice and append...

```
$arr = [0=>"a",1=>"b",2=>"c"];
$splice_value = 2;
$spliced_arr = array_splice($arr, $splice_value);
for($i=$splice_value; $i < count($arr); $i++)
{
   $spliced_arr[] = $arr[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you dont mind changing from associative array to a list

```
$outboundSummaryData = array_splice(
     array_values($outboundSummaryData), 
     2, 0, array('States ' => 'States', 'Call Count' => 'Call Count', 'Leads' => 'Leads')
);
```